# Does there exist an amazing poset that is neither totally-ordered nor well-founded?

Tags: order-theory

**Definition.** Let $P$ denote a poset. Then $P$ is *amazing* iff every $A \subseteq P$ has the property that if $A$ has a unique minimal element (call it $m$), then $A$ has a minimum element (namely $m.$)

> **Question.** Does there exist an amazing poset that is neither totally-ordered nor well-founded?

*Discussion.* Both total-orderedness and well-foundedness imply amazing. An example of a poset that isn't amazing is $\mathbb{Z} \sqcup \mathbb{Z}$. I haven't been able to think of any amazing posets that aren't either well-founded, or totally ordered.

Comment: Is the introduction of random terminology ("amazing") really necessary? Anyway, you probably know by now that a significant number of people dislike PSQ and consider them bad questions...

Comment: Amazing question! haha. Anyways sorry if this is a stupid question but I dont think to get the difference between minumum element and minimal. If exist **only one minimal** element $m$ ($\neg\exists p(p\in A)(p<m)$) then why $m$ is not the minumum $\forall p(p\in A)m\le p$?

Comment: @MphLee Consider the poset $\{x\} \cup \mathbb{Z}$ where $x$ is unrelated to $\mathbb{Z}$; then it has a unique minimal element, namely $x$ (because no element is less than $x$ and it's the only one like that), but it's not a minimum, because for example you don't have $x < 0$.

Comment: Got it! Thanks, it was so easy to see...

Comment: What are your own thoughts, and where did the question arise? The post does have the problem that it's just a PSQ at the moment.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi, I think its totally necessary. Discussing the problem would be very clumsy without some terminology. If you're critiquing the particular terminology I chose, then yes, I agree its amazingly cringeworthy (pun intended). But I'd rather not waste time trying to find good terminology. You can spend half an hour on thesaurus.com this way. Better to spend it doing actual math.

Comment: "Does there exist a poset $P$ which is neither totally ordered nor well founded, and such that for all $A \subset P$, if $A$ has a unique minimal element then $A$ has a minimum element." If you want, just call this property "(*)" or something.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi, sure, but you want to actually discuss the property. I don't mind the idea of calling it (*), but it still kind of forces you to alter your natural way of talking (to accommodate the fact that you haven't got an adjective). Anyway, I don't understand. You seem to be opposed to one-off terminology. If so, why? If not, what is bothering you?

Comment: Then just say "the property" if you want... There really is no need to invent another adjective when math is already bloated with completely random terminology. [This Wikipedia list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Classes_of_natural_numbers) is already depressing enough. Who thought "amicable number" or "narcissistic number" were good terminology...?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi, I do see your point. At the same time, I'd rather have some terminology available, even if its bad ("amicable number"), than not have it at all. As for this question, I would probably have just used $(*)$ if I had thought of it, which I didn't. In my opinion, the real problem is not that we name too many thing, but rather that we name the wrong things. e.g. We speak of "subsets" rather than "the powerset and its elements." This kind of thing creates a lot of unnecessary doubling-up, in my opinion.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi, hey how do you write a pretty looking (*) as a bullet point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about $\mathbb Z$ with the $0$ split into two different elements? The zeroes are not comparable, but both are smaller than every positive number and larger than every negative number.

More generally if $A$ is a totally ordered but ill-founded set and $B$ is any set, with $\ge 2$ elements, then $A\times B$ where $(a,b)<(a',b')$ iff $a<a'$.

Comment: @CarlMummert: A two-element poset is well-founded. (The positive elements in my example are not needed, but the negative ones are there specifically to make it ill-founded).

Comment: Nice example. $\;$

Comment: Henning, do you know of a more intuitive characterization of the property of interest? More generally, I'd be interested in more information, if you have it. The question that's bugging me mostly, I think, is "how do you actually build these things?" Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: @goblin: Do you mean amazingness? I'm not sure I have any good coherent intuition about it. "Minimal elements are always minimums" would feel like a sensible property, but "_unique_ minimal elements are minimums" feels a bit off to me. Where do you have this property from?

Comment: The problem with "minimal elements are always minimums" is that it forces total-orderedness. For suppose a poset $X$ has this property. Suppose $A \subseteq X$ is an antichain of cardinality $\mathbf{2}$. Assume $A = \{a,b\}$. Then since every element in an antichain is minimal, hence both $a$ and $b$ are minimal, hence they're both minimum, so they're equal. But this contradicts that $A$ has cardinality $\mathbf{2}$. The point of amazingness is to allow for partial orderedness (there's no further motivation for amazingness at the moment, I literally just made it up.)

Comment: @goblin: Okay -- it's so sensible that it coincides with an already-known concept. There can be too much of a good thing, I suppose :-)

Comment: :-) $\;\!\;\!\;\!$